# target binary can't link to mogodb libs installed by conan

Tags: mongodb, cmake, conan

I've got cpp project that uses `mongo-cxx-driver`. Here is conanfile.py for the project:

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools


class TradingBotConan(ConanFile):
    name = "bot"
    version = "0.1"
    description = "bot"
    url = "gitlab url here"

    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "cmake_find_package_multi"

    def configure(self):
        if self.settings.compiler == "gcc"\
           and self.settings.compiler.libcxx != "libstdc++11":
            raise ConanException("libstdc++11 required for build, yours is %s" % self.settings.compiler.libcxx.value)

        #here some unrelated qt options

        self.options["mongo-cxx-driver"].polyfill = "std"
        self.options["mongo-c-driver"].shared = True
        self.options["mongo-cxx-driver"].shared = True

    def requirements(self):
        #here some unrelated requirements
        self.requires('mongo-cxx-driver/3.6.2')

    def _configure_cmake(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        return cmake

    def build(self):
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.install()
        self.output.info("-----self-package------")
        self.copy(pattern="*.so*", src="commons/lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
```

when I call `conan build` then final executable conatins correct links to mongodb libraries:

```
        ldd ../build/bin/trading_bot
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff215d8000)
        libmongocxx.so._noabi => /home/conan/.conan/data/mongo-cxx-driver/3.6.2/_/_/package/6358f3985b8cd3d048645b6a0e52399f4d07e8f5/lib/libmongocxx.so._noabi (0x00007f8dd48ac000)
        libbsoncxx.so._noabi => /home/conan/.conan/data/mongo-cxx-driver/3.6.2/_/_/package/6358f3985b8cd3d048645b6a0e52399f4d07e8f5/lib/libbsoncxx.so._noabi (0x00007f8dd4888000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8dd487b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8dd4699000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8dd4674000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8dd466a000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8dd451b000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8dd4500000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8dd430e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8dd596a000)
        libmongoc-1.0.so.0 => /home/conan/.conan/data/mongo-c-driver/1.23.2/_/_/package/46bd0720cd3f3f4c567b3242a9879e8d8e0629d5/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8dd3d15000)
        libbson-1.0.so.0 => /home/conan/.conan/data/mongo-c-driver/1.23.2/_/_/package/46bd0720cd3f3f4c567b3242a9879e8d8e0629d5/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8dd3cce000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8dd3cb2000)
```

however when I call `conan package` then (after cmake install) final executable file doesn't have links to mongo libs:

```
conan@5c45aca5eefb:/app/scripts$ ldd ../package/bin/trading_bot
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd72927000)
        libmongocxx.so._noabi => not found
        libbsoncxx.so._noabi => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f27e80dc000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f27e7efa000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f27e7ed7000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f27e7ecd000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f27e7d7c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f27e7d61000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f27e7b6f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f27e90f8000)
```

I tried to add

```
    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.components["mongocxx"].requires = ["mongo-cxx-driver::mongocxx", "mongo-cxx-driver::bsoncxx"]
```

but it didn't help. So the question is how to configure conan file in order to make it work?
Here is CMakeListsFile for the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(trading-bot CXX)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
  add_compile_options(-g3)
endif()

if(CONAN_EXPORTED)
  set(CONAN_EXPORTED OFF)
endif()

if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
  message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
  file(DOWNLOAD "https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/raw/v0.15/conan.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake"
    TLS_VERIFY ON)
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)
add_subdirectory(commons)
conan_cmake_run(
  CONANFILE conanfile.py
  BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
  BUILD missing
  BASIC_SETUP CMAKE_TARGETS KEEP_RPATHS)

add_subdirectory(interfaces)
add_subdirectory(mongodb-adapter)
add_subdirectory(redis)
add_subdirectory(trading_bot)
add_subdirectory(migrations)

install(TARGETS trading_bot RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config/trading_bot_config.yaml ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/trading_bot_config.yaml COPYONLY)
```

Comment: The linker doesn't know where to find those libraries.  What happens with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/conan/.conan/data/mongo-cxx-driver/3.6.2/_/_/package/6358f3985b8cd3d048645b6a0e52399f4d07e8f5/lib/ ldd ../package/bin/trading_bot`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs then everything is ok, all links are correct. How to tell linker where to find this libs in conan/cmake file?

Comment: Beware of the usage of legacy, deprecated features like ``cmake_find_package_multi`` generator, superseded by ``CMakeDeps`` (the former has been even removed in 2.0). If you are starting with Conan, probably start with 2.0 or at least make sure to use modern features: https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/tools.html

Comment: @drodri unfortunately I use conan 1.59, so CMakeDeps isn't implemented here. I'm not sure if I can move to conan 2.0 now

Comment: Also, it seems that there are unused code there: the ``cmake-conan`` integration is only for consuming, but when using ``conan build`` it shouldn't be used at all, could be simplified for the report. If using ``conan build`` I'd recommend dropping ``cmake-conan`` integration.

Comment: CMakeDeps has been implemented in 1.X since many releases ago: https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/tools.html. It was introduced in January 2021: https://docs.conan.io/1/changelog.html

Comment: It's unrelated to linker. ldd says `not found` because after installation by CMake, RUNPATH is removed from binary. It's your responsibility to either use VirtualRunEnv generator to inject paths to conan dependencies into LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running this executable, or change RUNPATH of your executable to hardcode some paths.